# Trouble inflating CardView for use in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have a `RecyclerView` that displays several `CardView`s.

This is a simplified version of the layout I am attempted to inflate (just some more `TextView`s:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/background_floating_material_dark"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/waypoint_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/placeholder_waypoint_name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
        android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

From the stack traces, I know that these are the lines that are causing problems (in the adapter for my `RecyclerView`):

```
try {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.waypoint_list_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
} catch (InflateException e) {
    Log.wtf("ViewHolder", e.getCause());
    throw e;
}
```

I am printing both the thrown exception and the actual cause of the exception. ([This](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#632) shows that the true exception is being masked.)

The two outputs I got from this are the first exception, and the wrapping `InflateException`:

First exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at APPLICATION_PACKAGE.WaypointAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(WaypointAdapter.java:51)
            at APPLICATION_PACKAGE.WaypointAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(WaypointAdapter.java:24)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:4121)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3431)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3340)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1810)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1306)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1269)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:523)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:1988)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2237)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1594)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:502)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1829)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:7
```

Wrapping `InflateException`:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at APPLICATION_PACKAGE.WaypointAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(WaypointAdapter.java:51)
            at APPLICATION_PACKAGE.WaypointAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(WaypointAdapter.java:24)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:4121)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3431)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3340)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1810)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1306)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1269)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:523)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:1988)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2237)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1594)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:502)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1829)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Hand
```

Also, here are the relevant lines from the `build.gradle` (I'm using Android Studio) that correspond to this application:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

This is all the useful information I could think to include, but I'm happy to add anything extra. Similar issue point to the `CardView` library not being included, but I believe I have that solved by including it in the dependencies section. I had a previous version of this working before, but I cannot get it to work again - even after undoing all changes I can remember.

Comment: are you using viewpager at some place? bcoz the logcat shows that

Comment: Yes, the whole fragment (that wraps the `RecyclerView`) is inside a `ViewPager`. I had it working inside the `ViewPager` earlier, and I gone back to pretty much the same as that (from memory). Since I had a similar design working before, I'm not sure what part is not working.

Comment: I have similar issue, found *unanswered* related question here, [Error inflating class <unknown> - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178689/error-inflating-class-unknown-android).




Following both.