# Error inflating class <unknown> - Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on an Android App , Here I am working with RecyclerView . I have an item.xml for RecyclerView .

**item.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/userpopstcardview"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    cardView:cardElevation="2dp"
    cardView:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    cardView:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/listview_corner"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/user_placeholder"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/circleView"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:text="Jasmine"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/location"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="#929292"
                            android:maxLines="2"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textStyle="normal"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/time"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="#929292"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textStyle="normal"
                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/hours_minuts"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="#929292"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textStyle="normal"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="#929292"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textStyle="normal"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/massage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="#303030">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/attachment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:tint="#00000000"
                    />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/player_toolbar"
                    android:background="#30000000"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/audioTime"
                        android:text="00:00"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_size"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:gravity="center"/>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/player_control"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_size"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/player_state"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:src="@drawable/play"
                            android:tint="#00000000"
                            />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/selected_title"
                        android:text=""
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/audioTime"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/player_control"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                </RelativeLayout>

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="#fff">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/likespoints"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="#929292"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/likeList"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_effect"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Likes"
                    android:textColor="#929292"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/commentspoints"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="#929292"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Comments"
                    android:textColor="#929292"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:background="#eeeeee"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/like"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Like"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="#929292"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_effect"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="0.5dp">
                <View
                    android:layout_width="0.5dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#eeeeee"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/comment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Comment"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="#929292"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_effect"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="0.5dp">
                <View
                    android:layout_width="0.5dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#eeeeee"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/share"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Share"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="#929292"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_effect"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I have inflated item.xml using following code in **onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType)**

```
View itemViewTextAudio = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
```

But it is crashing at above line . I have visited many posts on Stackoverflow ,but no luck .

LogCat :

```
Process: com.musomeet, PID: 27659
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #150: Binary XML file line #150: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at com.adapter.UserPostAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(UserPostAdapter.java:340)
at com.adapter.UserPostAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(UserPostAdapter.java:30)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5288)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4551)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4461)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1962)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1371)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1334)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:563)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2847)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3145)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreograph
```

**Edit :**

item.xml is displaying perfectly on Lollipop based devices but it is not being displayed on **Huawei Nexus 6P** which is Marshmallow based Android phone .

Note : When I try setContentView(R.layout.item) then works fine on **Huawei Nexus 6P** .
but It is throwing error when using with following code :

```
View itemViewTextAudio = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
```

Comment: whats the 150 line in your xml file?

Comment: It is TextView with android:id="@+id/audioTime" .

Comment: you said the above xml is `item.xml` but the one you inflated is `R.layout.userposts_listitem_audioandtext`

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Right , its original name is userposts_listitem_audioandtext.xml .

Comment: same issue here, following.