# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to open a new `Fragment` containing a `RecyclerView` with `CardView`s. It's a common list of products.

I am faced with the following error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class <unknown>

    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.projecttango.examples.cpp.planefitting.CatalogueItemAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(CatalogueItemAdapter.java:41)
    at com.projecttango.examples.cpp.planefitting.CatalogueItemAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(CatalogueItemAdapter.java:16)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6078)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5248)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5158)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2061)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:562)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1408)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:580)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3379)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3188)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3632)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1193)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2085)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1830)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1082)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5827)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:774)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:587)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:760)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5030)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25371):    at java.lang.r
W/ActivityManager(  905):   Force finishing activity com.projecttango.examples.cpp.planefitting/.MainActivity
```

XML for the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code for the fragment:

```
public class CatalogueFragment extends Fragment {
    ArrayList catalogueItems;
    CatalogueItemAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        setupCatalogue(rootView);
        return rootView;
    }
    private void setupCatalogue(View view) {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        catalogueItems = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new CatalogueItemAdapter(getActivity(), catalogueItems);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 4);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        addCatalogueItems();//adds entries to catalogueItems
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

My adapter:

```
public class CatalogueItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CatalogueItemAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<CatalogueItem> catalogueItems;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, count;
        public ImageView thumbnail;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        }
    }


    public CatalogueItemAdapter(Context mContext, List<CatalogueItem> catalogueItems) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.catalogueItems = catalogueItems;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.catalogue_item, parent, false);//<-- breaks here
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CatalogueItem album = catalogueItems.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(album.getName());
        holder.count.setText("£" + album.getPrice());

        // loading album cover using Glide library
        Glide.with(mContext).load(album.getImageURL()).into(holder.thumbnail);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return catalogueItems.size();
    }
}
```

XML for the cards (`catalogue_item.xml`):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_album_radius">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/album_cover_height"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/product_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/album_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/count"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:textSize="@dimen/songs_count" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129804/discussion-on-question-by-bujanca-mihai-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xm).

Comment: I have similar issue, found *unanswered* related questions here, [Error inflating class <unknown> - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178689/error-inflating-class-unknown-android) and [Trouble inflating CardView for use in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405456/trouble-inflating-cardview-for-use-in-recyclerview).








Following all, all are unanswered. And I think all will have similar solutions.

Comment: use android recyclerview from android x

Answer (score 0):

The property `background` seems causing this issue. Remove it from xml and try to set from java/kotlin

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```